# Check if a html element is shown with protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm testing a simple checkbox that displays a pop up when checked. When I run my e2e test I see the pop up is being displayed after the checkbox gets checked. The result of the test however is false. Why does the `isPresent()` function return false? Is there some kind of delay?

This is the code of my e2e test:

```
it('should display popup window if button is checked', function () {
    var popUp = element(by.binding('who.othersIncluded'));
    element(by.id('othersIncl')).click();
    expect(popUp.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

This is the html:

```
<input id="othersIncl" class="input-checkbox-alt" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="who.othersIncluded" data-ng-change="update()"/>

<div data-ng-show="who.othersIncluded">
    <div>hidden popup</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `by.binding` is the wrong locator. you may have to search by.css, by.tagName, etc. `element(by.css('div .someClass #anId'))`

Comment: @nilsK how would I do that if the div only contains an ng-show?

Comment: i can not answer that, without knowing your template. without any classes or ids to locate your popup directly, you could use one of the folliwing locators: by.css, by.tagName, by.xpath (and maybe others i forgot) anyway: take a look at [locators](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md) and i suggest using [page objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) if you are not already doing this.

Comment: @nilK thanks for your help. I found the answer and posted it below. However I am not sure if this is the most efficient way regarding the stability of the test. What exactly do you mean by template?

Comment: i meant your hmtl template, not just the snippet you postet above. e.g.: if your snippet would be wrapped inside a <div class="my-class"> container, you could locate it for example with `element(by.className('my-class')).element(by.css('div'))`.

Comment: Okee thanks I didn't know that was possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to make it work!

This is the working code to select the html div with the ng-show attribute:

```
popUp = $('[data-ng-show="who.othersIncluded"]');
```

This returns an element that can be used in the expectation.